# Eclipse Sonar report not exist in SonarQube remote server

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarlint

I want to integrate Sonar in Eclipse and I want to see the analysis report on remote SonarQube server. Should I only run the analysis from my Eclipse after binding my Eclipse project to a project which is created manually from SonarQube server web interface (http://X.X.X.X:9000)? Or Should I also copy the project to SonarQube server then run the `sonar-runnar` bash command to analysis it?

I configured a SonarQube server in Linux. Then I added Sonarlint plugin to Eclipse and I linked a project in Eclipse with a project in SonarQube server. But when I run the analyse in the Eclipse, I don't see any report on remote SonarQube server.

Is there any way to see the report of Eclipse Sonarlint on the remote SonarQube server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's the goal. SonarLint won't post anything on remote server. Sonarlint just run analyse on local Eclipse.

If you want repport on sonarqube server you have to run a scan, with command line client, or with your maven build, or run with your jenkins if you use  it.